# If Statement in argument of Vlookup Function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I wrote a formula that checks some values, and depending on the result returns a number. How do I, by analogy, pass to the second argument of the WorksheetFunction function.VLookup?

Formula:

```
"=VLOOKUP(""Text Test"",IF(IF(Sheet2!R6C2<0.91,""< 0,91"","">=0,91"")='pril20'!R6C2:R21C2,'pril20'!R6C1:R21C3,""""),3,0)"
```

I got this formula when writing a macro.

My code:

```
Sub test1()

    Dim x
    x = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(""Text Test"",IF(IF(Sheet2!R6C2<0.91,""< 0,91"","">=0,91"")='pril20'!R6C2:R21C2,'pril20'!R6C1:R21C3,""""),3,0)
    MsgBox x
    End Sub
```

So, I have a syntax error when I try to pass the "IF" condition as the second argument. How do I do it by analogy with the function =VLOOKUP?

Comment: Your formula makes no sense at all to me. Please explain in words what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If your original formula makes sense, just use `x=Evaluate(formulatext)` and be done with it :)

Comment: @milo5m
Thank you very much! But I don't understand why I get an error in the cells when I try to run the Evaluate command. The formula makes sense and does the correct calculations in Excel. It seems to me that references to ranges in sheets look incorrect for VBA. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Who was talking about calling the sub/evaluating **from a cell**? Did you use your code as it is, only replacing your way of calculating `x` with the above suggested way? Does `MsgBox` return correctly?

Comment: @Foertschfor example `""Text Test""` should be `"Text Test"`, `IF` should be `IIF`, you can't use `Sheet1!R6C2` to name a few problems

Comment: Try using `x=Evaluate("VLOOKUP(""Text Test"",IF(IF(Sheet2!R6C2<0.91,""< 0,91"","">=0,91"")='pril20'!R6C2:R21C2,'pril20'!R6C1:R21C3,""""),3,0)")`

Answer (score 1):

Lazy method using Evaluate

```
Sub test1()
    Dim x as variant
    
    x=Evaluate("VLOOKUP(""Text Test"",IF(IF(Sheet2!R6C2<0.91,""< 0,91"","">=0,91"")='pril20'!R6C2:R21C2,'pril20'!R6C1:R21C3,""""),3,0)")
    if Not IsError(x) then: MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Also equivalent of `Sheet1!R6C2` in VBA would be
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 2)`